# can't change languages from lock screen

Tags: login, lightdm, lock-screen, language-support

I use Arabic and english languages on ubuntu 19.04 . If the screen gets locked while on Arabic i can't switch the keyboard to english so i have to restart the `lightdm service` so i can get to the initial login screen and i can access the  account

any suggestion why this happens and how i can fix it

i tried to modify `/etc/default/keyboard`  and this is the content now

```
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBLAYOUT=us,ar
XKBVARIANT=,
```

i cant see now the icon to change languages but i doesn't switch the languages

Answer (score -1):

**workaround**

i found the issue is in the lock screen not in the greeter so i changed the following

1. I disabled the auto lock from `setting > privacy >Screen` lock
2. Then changed the keyboard shortcut for lock screen from super+L to
   ALT+CTL+Shift+F11
3. I made a new shortcut for the following command `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` with keyboard shortcut super+L